# Matching weights vs 'weighting' weights?

Tags: causality, matching, weighted-regression

What is the difference between matching weights obtained from full matching (with propensity score or mahalanobis distance, using MatchIt and then match.data in R) and the "weighing" weights (obtained from WeighIt in R)? And should one be preferred over the other (especially when the sample size is small)?

Comment: I have a blog post about this very question :) https://ngreifer.github.io/blog/matching-weights/

Comment: Thank so much! So from the blog I interpret that conducting full matching using MatchIt followed by match.data would give me exactly the same weights as using WeightIt with method = "glm". The only difference is that the WeighIt approach could be used for continuous treatments (ie. >2 treatments in each stratum). Is that correct?

Comment: Nope. Re-read the paragraph starting with "Note that $\hat{e}^*_i$ is distinct from $\hat{e}_i$". The full matching weights come from the organization of units into strata; the IPW weights (from `weightit()`) come from the propensity scores estimated using logistic regression.

Comment: Right, thank you! So how should one decide if to use full matching weights or IPW weights? Does full matching just give you more flexibility than IPW weights (with the stratum propensity scores and matching being conducted separately in the former and  at the matching stage many options exist, eg with regards to the distance - propensity vs mahalanobis)

Comment: Many options exist for both matching and weighting. See my paper [here](https://doi.org/10.1093/epirev/mxab003) for some guidance on choosing between them. Ultimately the choice should be made based on the method that provides the greatest effective sample size, the best balance, and the best representativeness of your target population.